# Problematic lines for black in accelerated dragon

Tags: opening, sicilian-defense

What are Difficult lines for black in accelerated dragon?the most problematic line for black in the accelerated dragon

Comment: This is a very broad question. Could you be more specific? Also, do you mean "What should white play to give black problems?" or "What moves should black avoid because they cause problems?"

Comment: I disagree about the broadness of the question.  The Yugoslav is always a challenge.
1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 g6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 Nc6 5.Nc3 Bg7 6.Be3 Nf6 7.Bc4
O-O 8.Bb3 d6 9.f3 Bd7 10.Qd2 *

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you play the accelerated through the move order 1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 cxd4 4.Nxd4 g6 then the most problematic would be the  maroczy bind after 5.c4.

But then through that move order you may not even get it as opponents may instead of 3.d4 play 3.Bb5 (Rossolimo) which is very popular.

If you play it through the move order 1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 g6 then by far the most testing line is 3.d4 cxd4 4.Qxd4 and both sides have to be very well prepared but black more than white for sure.